# How can I increase the maximum search results in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, when I perform a search that is not "narrow" on a vast folder, I get an error message stating the following:

> The result set only contains a subset of all matches. Be more specific
> in your search to narrow down the results.

Is there a way/setting to avoid this message and continue the search in Visual Studio Code?

The search is expected to return about 50,000 - 70,000 matches.

Comment: if you want to see them all use a grep on the command line and use file redirection, you are not going to visit each of the 50k+ hits in the editor, then open the result file and search here

Comment: @rioV8 Hi, thanks for trying to help. Well, my bad for not mentioning this minor detail in my question which is that I will be performing a search/replaceAll operation on these records, and secondly I don't really know much about grep so I need a solution that is VSCode specific, if possible. If not, then can you explain how this would work in grep? thanks in advance.

Comment: @rioV8 Also, don't worry about the specs in case you are wondering, the machine I am working on is actually 256GB of ram and a decent CPU so it won't be a problem to perform this search/replaceAll.

Comment: for really large search replace I use a python script with arguments to control what and which files. If you want to use VSC make sure that you can do the search/replace in batches, the search does not match replaced items, maybe you need to add an unused char sequence `@#@#` and in pass 2 remove this char sequence from the files. VSC has a limit on the max multi cursors, I have to deal with it, VSC has a limit on the max file size you can open with `vscode.open`

Comment: @rioV8 The file sizes are tiny, but the number of files is large, the search really isn't complete, it's an extremely simple regex that searches for a specific record that appears in all files and replaces them.

Comment: then apply the search in batches of 50k cases, or you can always use `sed` or `awk` to process the files, or even `m4` (I haven't used it)

Comment: but you now still have a max results, using a filter command line tool has NO limits, that is one of the powers of `sed` and `awk`, you can write awk scripts in the command line if you just do simple search replace on line basis and then use `xargs` and `find` to process all the files you want

Comment: @rioV8 I fully agree with you but in the case of my question, I only needed to perform the search/replaceAll function on a specific number of records (50K-70K) and not unlimited. Secondly, you can also set the limit settting to `-1` to make it unlimited, let me also add that in my answer. Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: @rioV8 Actually, I rechecked and it turns out that `-1` was used in very old versions of VS Code and now you can leave it empty/null to make it unlimited.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution for this is already in Visual Studio Code.

Here are the steps:

1. You go to the settings of Visual Studio Code by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and searching for an option that goes **Preferences: Open User Settings**, click it.
2. In the settings section there will be a search bar with the placeholder of "Search settings", in it type, "Search: Max Results".
3. By now, there will be an option with the heading of **Search: Max Results** and a default value (at the time of writing) of "20,000", change that to a higher number like "100,000" or to empty/`null` (to make it completely unlimited), and save the settings.

Or add the following to your *settings.json* file with whatever maximum value you'd like:

```json
{
  "search.maxResults": 40000
}
```

You should now be able to perform search/replace operations with larger search results in Visual Studio Code.

**See Also**: [Add search.maxResults setting #126762](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/126762)

Comment: thanks man, you saved me many hours  